# GDAL osgeo for python treating Z dimension differently

Tags: python, gdal, geometry, ogr, osgeo

I have a space defined by a polyhedral surface, and I would like to check if a point is inside this space, and I would like to do this in python with gdal.

After trying the default installation of gdal with conda, there were some functions that did not work that I wanted regarding sfcgal, so I compiled gdal from source with sfcgal (as this seemed to contain extra 3D functionality) and geos,for python3. I have tried the following in python:

```
>>> from osgeo import ogr
>>> ps2 = 'POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((0 0 0,0 0 1,0 1 1,0 1 0,0 0 0)),((0 0 0,0 1 0,1 1 0,1 0 0,0 0 0)),((0 0 0,1 0 0,1 0 1,0 0 1,0 0 0)),((1 1 0,1 1 1,1 0 1,1 0 0,1 1 0)),((0 1 0,0 1 1,1 1 1,1 1 0,0 1 0)),((0 0 1,1 0 1,1 1 1,0 1 1,0 0 1)))'
>>> geom2 = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(ps2)
>>> geom2.CloseRings()
>>> point3 = 'POINT Z (0.5 1.5 0.5)'
>>> point3_g = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(point3)
>>> point3_g.Within(geom1)
False
>>> # This is correct behavior
>>> point2 = 'POINT Z (0.5 0.5 1.5)'
>>> point2_g = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(point2)
>>> point2_g.Within(geom1)
True
>>> # This is unexpected behavior!
```

Is there anything I am missing for gdal to treat the Z dimension like one of the other dimensions?